# J2ME Access To 3G Camera

Tags: java-me

I have a SE W660 and I would like to take a snapshot from the 3G camera (which is on the front, and not on the back).

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to that device right now.  But JSR135 lets you find out all the possible capture options by calling `Manager.getSupportedContentTypes("capture")`.  This will return a string array of capture types.  You can then try each one in turn (using `Manager.createPlayer("capture://" + <capture string>)`) and see if one of them corresponds to the front camera.

If it helps, on Nokia S60 the strings `"capture://devcam0"` and `"capture://devcam1"` provide access to the main and secondary cameras respectively.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It goes something like this:

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
player.realize();
VideoControl vc = (VideoControl) player .getControl("VideoControl");
player.start();
byte[] imageData = vc.getSnapshot(null);
Image snapshot = Image.createImage(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```

some more info [here](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/community/docs/DOC-2594)